# Drawing part of image in Direct2D

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d, drawbitmap

Since GDI+ is pretty (ridiculously) slow, I've decided to migrate to Direct2D. I've looked up many topics on many forums (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759803/rendering-part-of-a-bitmap-using-direct2d)), but with no success (it may also be caused by the fact that's pretty late) and the Direct2D documentation is pretty slim still (and confusing, for me at least).

Anyway, I've got a .PNG that I open in Direct2D and want to draw only a part of it once every 20ms.

Initialize D2D stuff

```
ID2D1Factory* d2dFactory = NULL;
IWICImagingFactory* d2dWICFactory = NULL;
IWICBitmapDecoder* d2dDecoder = NULL;
IWICFormatConverter* d2dConverter = NULL;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* d2drender = NULL;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode* d2dBmpSrc = NULL;
ID2D1Bitmap* d2dBmp = NULL;

/* initialize all the good stuff */
HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
               __uuidof(ID2D1Factory), NULL, (void**)&d2dFactory);    

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

hr = d2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
               D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(zgE->getWnd(), size), &d2drender);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                   __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory), (void**)(&d2dWICFactory));

hr = d2dWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(L"tile_1.png", NULL, GENERIC_READ,
                                      WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &d2dDecoder);

hr = d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&d2dConverter);

hr = d2dDecoder->GetFrame(0, &d2dBmpSrc);

hr = d2dConverter->Initialize(d2dBmpSrc, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
              WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);

hr = d2drender->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(d2dConverter, NULL, &d2dBmp);
```

Drawing:

```
/* draw the image */
D2D1_RECT_F rect = D2D1::RectF(x, y, x + size.width, y + size.height);
d2drender->DrawBitmap(d2dBmp, &rect);
```

However, I can't get it to draw only a part of it, lets say 20 by 20 pixels. I've fiddled with `DrawBitmap()` and with differently sized `rect`s, but the result isn't cropping the image.

Is there any way to do it *besides layering, since I don't want to layer the image at each frame*?

Comment: what result did you actually got?

Comment: Only got it to be diplayed whole at 1:1 or scaled or stretched depending on the sizes of the rect in the parameter. Also, tried another DrawBitmap() overload (with 2 rects - dont have the code with me) but nothing.

Comment: where is the code to split the whole bitmap? if you didn't split it, how did you draw part of it?

Comment: well that's it, i don't know how to split it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly three steps

1. Create the entire bitmap from file
2. Get part of the entire bitmap by calling [CopyFromBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. Draw bitmap created in step 2.

Comment: One mention is that you have to create another bitmap in which you copy the portion from the big bitmap. Anyway, thanks, it worked.

Comment: This is a really unnecessarily inefficient solution, rick's answer is much better.

Answer (score 4):

`ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawBitmap` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371880(v=vs.85).aspx ) takes up to 5 parameters, the last one being the source rectangle. You're only supplying the first 2 parameters, and the default for the source rectangle is to use the entire bitmap. So, the solution is simply to supply this parameter with a `D2D1::RectF(0, 0, 20, 20)` if you only want to draw from that portion of it.